# How to send a SYN packet and not sending the ACK response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("HOST", PORT))
```

This code surely send a SYN packet to HOST, but does it complete the three-way handshake? Does it send the ACK packet to HOST?

If not, how can I make socket not sending the ACK packet?

That's because I'm trying to study the syn flood flaws and how this attack works. So SYN packets are sent but no ACK packets response are sent.

Comment: `connect` does the ACK. You could open `SOCK_RAW` and construct the packets yourself. But  there has got to be packages out there that already do that.

Comment: Of course: [scapy](https://pypi.org/project/scapy/), the "powerful Python-based interactive packet manipulation program and library"

Answer (score 1):

The `.connect()` call is asking the kernel to setup a usable socket
with the standard 3-way handshake:

1. SYN →
2. ← SYN+ACK
3. ACK →

To send packets, without creating a usable socket, call [`hping3`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hping3) instead:

```
$ sudo hping3 -i u1 -S -p 80 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: My goal would be to create a program myself, not to use a program created by other people.